# How to generate arbitrary two argument function with QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am trying to test my implementation of `zipWith` using QuickCheck. My implementation, `myZipWith`, I would like to QuickCheck test by comparing to the standard function. Something like:

```
main = do
  quickCheck (prop_myZipWith :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool)

prop_myZipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> Bool
prop_myZipWith f x y = (myZipWith x y) == (zipWith f x y)
```

This does not work because `(Int -> Int -> Int)` is not an instance of `Arbitrary`.

With single-argument functions one can get around this using [`Test.QuickCheck.Function`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html#t::-45--62-)'s `Fun` (which instantiates `Arbitrary`). For example:

```
main = do
  quickCheck (prop_myMap :: Fun Int Int -> [Int] -> Bool)

prop_myMap :: Fun a b -> [a] -> Bool
prop_myMap (Fun _ f) l = (myMap f l) == (map f l)
```

I am trying to do something similar except generating *two*-argument arbitrary functions.

**How can I generate arbitrary instances of two argument functions** for QuickCheck testing of higher-order functions such as `zipWith`?

Comment: Can't you just exploit currying and use `Fun Int (Fun Int Int)`? Remember that there's no such a thing as a binary function, since everything is curried.

Comment: Note that the statement "This does not work because (Int -> Int -> Int) is not an instance of Arbitrary." is false (functions *are* instances of Arbitrary). It doesn't work because functions aren't instances of `Show`. But as @chi says, currying solves your problem in a trivial way (and also in the only slightly less trivial way that `Fun (Int, Int) Int` would work as well). You may find the definitions `unFun (Fun _ f) = f; unFun2 f = unFun . unFun f` useful.

Comment: @chi, my limited experience in practice suggests that `Fun (a,b,...) x` is less painful to work with than `Fun a (Fun b (... x ...))`

Comment: If your next question is "what about higher-order functions?", then that was mine too. But that appears to be Very Hard. Koen Claessen wasn't able to find a satisfactory solution, so you should only consider it if you want a research project.

Answer (score 4):

## QuickCheck 2.9.2

With QuickCheck 2.9.2, you can use the `Fun` type, and the `Fn` pattern. You'll have to

```
import Test.QuickCheck.Function
```

You can then write the property using a tuple as input, and then `curry` the function:

```
prop_myZipWith :: Eq c => Fun (a, b) c -> [a] -> [b] -> Bool
prop_myZipWith (Fn f) x y = myZipWith (curry f) x y == zipWith (curry f) x y
```

`main` looks like this:

```
main =
  quickCheck (prop_myZipWith :: Fun (Int, Int) Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool)
```

This compiles, and the test passes, in my repro.

## QuickCheck 2.10.0.1

With QuickCheck 2.10.0.1, you can instead use the `Fn2` pattern, like this:

```
prop_myZipWith :: Eq c => Fun (a, b) c -> [a] -> [b] -> Bool
prop_myZipWith (Fn2 f) x y = myZipWith f x y == zipWith f x y
```

The main method remains the same, because the type of `prop_myZipWith` hasn't changed, but `import Test.QuickCheck.Function` is no longer required.